# How to retrieve column selectivity metadata in MySQL, without creating an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sqlperformance

Assuming the following SQL query:

```
SELECT col1,col2 from table where col1 > 5 and col2 > 8
```

I believe that MySQL won't be able to look up in both columns using the same table index, because both conditions are range conditions.
Therefore, I'm trying to understand what will be the best way to figure out which column to index in such scenario (which is probably the most selective one).

Is MySQL metadata accessible in a way that will allow one to identify whether column A or B are more selective, without actually creating the indexes for both options and looking at the cardinality information?

Edit: to clarify, the goal is to find a way to do that even for queries that take forever to run without the indexes (so counting rows is out of question in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Note that your query has *only* `col1` and `col2` in it.  This means that `INDEX(col1,col2)` and `INDEX(col2,col1)` are "covering".  "Covering gives an extra boost because the entire query can be performed in the index's BTree.

If you add another column to the `SELECT` list, it will no longer be covering.

But the question was about *which* order to put the columns in the index. 
 Think of it as a 2-dimensional array of things.  `col1 > 5 and col2 > 8` refers to the lower-right corner of that 2D array.  MySQL will essentially have to scan the right 'half' or the lower 'half' of the array, since the 1-dimensional index is ordered first by rows or columns.

The 'new' "MRR" feature of optimization *may* be able to focus the effort on the corner instead of a half.  Here's a way to find out:

```
add one index
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SELECT SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
drop that index
```

Now repeat with the other index.

Then compare the Handler values.  The biggest number will indicate the number of index (or data) rows that were touched.

**Simpler answer**

If the *only* columns in the query are `col1` and `col2`, then add `INDEX(col1, col2)` (in either order).

If more columns are involved, add `INDEX(col1)` and `INDEX(col2)`.  The Optimizer pick between them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Rick. I was actually looking for a way to determine which index to add without running a count query, nor adding the indexes and 'testing something' for each of them.
Does MySQL have any information which I can get, from its metadata maybe, that will allow me to make that decision?
Trial and error of adding and removing indexes can just take too long for large tables and queries, especially when optimizing a lot of queries. I'm looking for a way to avoid that, if one exists.

Comment: 2 ranges is messy to handle; I added to my Answer a "Simpler answer".

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem running this query?

```
select count(*),
       sum(col1 > 5),
       sum(col2 > 8),
       sum( col1 > 5 and col2 > 8)
from t;
```

Whichever has the smallest value between the second and third columns is the most selective.

Note:  There can still be value to putting both columns in an index.  MySQL should be able to use the second key for the `where` clause without having to look up the data in the data pages.

Comment: I didn't write it explicitly (just edited the question), but my goal is to be able to identify the correct index even if the relevant count(*) query takes forever to run without the indexes. I'm trying to figure out if and how MySQL's optimizer does that, and to mimic the same actions.

Comment: @Tomer - I have been pondering, without success, for years how to automatically generate indexes.  The best I have is a [_Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).